# I have table with two column but i want to get result in four column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is my code

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
name char(25)
)

INSERT INTO Students(name) VALUES('Farhat')
INSERT INTO Students(name) VALUES('shoaib')
INSERT INTO Students(name) VALUES('rameez')
INSERT INTO Students(name) VALUES('rafay')
INSERT INTO Students(name) VALUES('ata')
INSERT INTO Students(name) VALUES('fakhar')


SELECT
CASE WHEN s.id%2=1 THEN s.id 
END AS Student_id,
CASE WHEN s.id%2=1 THEN  s.NAME END AS student_name,
CASE WHEN s.id%2=0 THEN s.id 
END AS Student_Id,
CASE WHEN s.id%2=0 THEN s.NAME END AS Student_Name
FROM students s
```

and Result is

```
1       Farhat     NULL     NULL  
NULL    NULL       2        shoaib  
3       rameez     NULL     NULL  
NULL    NULL       4        rafay                      
5       ata        NULL     NULL  
NULL    NULL       6        fakhar
```

But i want the result which will like this

```
1 Farhat     2  shoaib  
3 rameez     4  rafay  
5 ata        6  rakhar
```

Means i have two column in this table and i want to get result in four column

Comment: Just why!?! SQL is not intended to do formatting of data in columns. You should leave presentation out of SQL query and just use whatever programming language you're using to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay just because I thought it would be fun I tried something but I'd advise against using this.

```
SELECT s1.id, s1.name, s2.id, s2.name
FROM students s1, students s2
WHERE (s2.id - s1.id = 1 
AND s1.id %2 == 1);
```

There are some caveats, 1 if there is an odd number of students the last student will NOT be printed. (It simply doesn't handle that case and I can't think of any way to solve this.)

But in my opinion you should just do something like:

```
 data = DB.query("SELECT s.id, s.name FROM Students s");
 for (i=0; i < length(data); i++)
     for (j=0; j<2; j++)
         print data[i+j].id, data[i+j].name;
     endfor
     print "\n";
 endfor
```

Note that this is just pseudo code so you'll have to tweak it. (Also `i+j` is prone to overflowing the array)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT std1.id AS Student_Id, 
        std1.NAME AS Student_Name, 
        std2.id AS Student_Id, 
        std2.NAME AS Student_Name
FROM students std1, students std2
WHERE (std2.id - std1.id = 1
       AND std1.id %2 = 1);
```